# How to start Tomcat with a specific server.xml under Windows?

Tags: tomcat

This question has already been answered in [How to start Tomcat with a specific server.xml under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154668/how-to-start-tomcat-with-a-specific-server-xml-under-windows), but it only applies for .bat or .sh files. 
What is the solution when running tomcat as windows service?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed as a service using the built in windows service installer, it writes the config info to your registry.  I think you could use regedit to navigate under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Apache Software Foundation/Procrun 2.0/TomcatX/Parameters/Start
```

And change the `Params` key, appending your argument to the end.  I haven't tried this specifically, but I've changed things about (java opts) in the registry when using the windows service.

Otherwise you'd need to open up the .bat file that creates the service and change the appropriate lines, and recreate the service.

Comment: I tried that, but didn´t work. I don´t know exactly what parameter to add. In .bat file one can add -config /path/to/file, but what is the correct syntax for service? I need a solution that really works, not just guessing.